# Make hash from two arrays of different length, distribute elements evenly

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have two arrays of different length. I want to put them into hash, distributing elements as evenly as possible.

***EDIT***: Sorry, I realized that I did not provide enough input. By "as evenly as possible", I mean the following:

array1 always has more elements, than array2.

array2 elements are strings. The smallest unit is word.

***UPATED GOAL***
For the resulting hash I want the distribution of values to keys based on average word  to number ratio (all elements array2 to array1.join(" ").split(" ")). So that I have numbers distributed to strings as close to average as possible without breaking the integrity of strings. You can also present the result as :

```
result = {"The older son of a woman" =>[320, 321, 322, 323],...}
```

My apologies for confusion, I guess the purpose of the application made me think of this in some inverted fashion..

---

I can get the example code below working for some cases, but for some it does not.

```
array1.clear
array2.clear

array11 = [336, 337, 338, 339, 340, 342, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348]
array22 = ["New research", "suggests that hoarders have unique patterns", "of brain activity", "when faced with making decisions", "about their possessions."] 

array1 =  [320, 321, 322, 323, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 329, 331, 332, 333, 334] 
array2 = ["The older son of a woman", "killed at Sunday's mass shooting", "in Wisconsin said she was shot just", "after completing prayers."] 


def hash_from_arrays(array1, array2)
 hash  =  Hash.new{|h,k| h[k] = [] }
  arr_ratio = arr1_to_arr2_ratio(array2, array1)
  start =  0
  last_arr1_to_arr2 = Float(Float(array2.last.split(" ").length)*Float(arr_ratio)).floor
  array1.each_with_index do | element, index|
    arr1_for_arr2_ratio = Float(Float(array2[0].split(" ").length)*Float(arr_ratio)).floor
    hash[element] = array2[0]
    if arr1_for_arr2_ratio + start == index && array2.length > 1
      array2.shift
      start = index
    end
  end
  return hash
end



def arr1_to_arr2_ratio(array1, array2)
  word_count = 0.0
  array1.each{|string| word_count = word_count + string.split(" ").length}
  result = Float(array2.length) / word_count
  return result
end



 hash_from_arrays(array1, array2)
 => {320=>"The older son of a woman", 321=>"The older son of a woman", 322=>"The older son of a woman", 323=>"The older son of a woman", 324=>"The older son of a woman", 325=>"killed at Sunday's mass shooting", 326=>"killed at Sunday's mass shooting", 327=>"killed at Sunday's mass shooting", 328=>"in Wisconsin said she was shot just", 329=>"in Wisconsin said she was shot just", 331=>"in Wisconsin said she was shot just", 332=>"in Wisconsin said she was shot just", 333=>"after completing prayers.", 334=>"after completing prayers."}
```

***EDIT*** Updated the code, now it works for both arrays.. And I guess works in general... If someone can suggest a better solution, that would be great.

Comment: I read it one, then twice, then once again and I cannot understand what you mean "as evenly as possible". Could you just explaing the target result? What are the key-numbers? How the text lines relate to them? What should be evenedout? Text length? Line counts?

Comment: sorry for unclarity, I will update the question

Comment: You should put an input array and the desirable result.

Comment: input arrays are in the question. Desirable result is described (I hope) now more clearly, an exact desirable result would be hard, b/c that is what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0) Problem description:

I have two sets and I want to define a mapping between them.

First is a set of unique strings, named SS or "strings", and its item is called "a string".
The first set is finite, it consists of NStrings items.
Each string in the first set may consist of any number of words, denoted by NumWords(string).
Thus, the first set provides also a statistical property of an average word count per string, denoted by TargetAVG.

The second is a set of unique numbers, named KK or "keys", and its item is called "a key".
The second set is finite, it consists of NKeys items.
The exact value of those numbers is irrelevant, they are used just as unique identifiers.

It is guaranteed that the second set has more entries than the first.

I want to generate mapping MM between the first and second set.
Every item of the second set (keys) should be assigned exactly one item of the first set (strings).
This mapping must use each item of the first set (strings) at least once.
Any item of the first set (strings) may be used multiple times.
Thus, the mapping generates also a statistical property of a number of uses of a given item from first set (strings), denoted by NumUses(string).

I want to generate such mapping, that the number of words in the strings that were assigned to the keys
produces the same average of TargetAVG (or as close as possible), with the comment that the string
counts to the average as many times as many times it was used by the mapping.

1) restate:

problem:

> selecting a fixed number of differently-valued items from an fixed set of unique items to best fit to target total worth. The count of items to be selected is greater than the number of items, this some items must be selected many times.

extra restriction:

> each item must be selected at least once.

where:

> items = SS
>       target item count = NKeys
>       item value = NumWords(item) * NumUses(item)
>       target total worth = TargetAVG * NKeys  (= estimated total amount of words in the whole mapping)

2) let's try to reduce the problem complexity:

There are more keys than strings + each string MUST be used at least once + each key must be used exactly once.
Thus, a properly generated mapping will contain a subset that will consist of every one of the strings mapped to different keys.
Thus, a NString of the keys are already partially solved, because we know they must be matched one-to-one to each one of the strings,
  we just do not know the order. For example we know that some 30 out of 70 keys must be paired 1-to-1 to each one of 30 strings,
  but we do not know which key to which string. However, the exact order of assignement was never important, so we can even
  map them straightly: first to first, second to second, ... 30th to 30th.
And this is exactly what we do to reduce the problem.

Therefore:

> -) we can always reduce, becase there were more keys than strings
>   -) and on behalf of this, we will always be left with some leftover keys, exactly (NKeys-NStrings)
>   -) the partial solution that guarantees "each item must be selected at least once"

Sanity check:
The partial solution has used up NStrings of the keys, and we are left with (NKeys-NStrings) keys.
The final solution must achieve an average equal to TargetAVG.
We already used all NStrings of strings once over first NStrings of the keys.
This means that our partial solution is guaranteed to have internally an average of "TargetAVG".
We are left with some keys.
This means that the mapping for the rest of the keys also should have average of "TargetAVG", or as close as possible.
We have fulfilled the requirement, we may now use any of the strings any times, even zero.

Everything sounds great.

3) remaining problem:

problem type:

> selecting a fixed number of valued items to best fit to target total worth. Any item may me selected any number of times.

where:

> items = SS
>       target item count = (NKeys-NStrings)
>       item value = NumWords(item) * NumUses(item)
>       target total worth = TargetAVG * (NKeys-NStrings)  (= estimated total amount of words in the leftover mapping)

The important thing is that we want to have closest sum to the given value "S" by using exact "X" number of picks.
It means that it is not a general knapsack packing problem, but it is kind of its subclass, kind of a
[Change-making problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem). Lets try if it fits that:

> We need to deal an amount of cash with the least use of differently-valued coins.
>     =>
>     We need to split a specified amount of words between some strings of different word count with exactly X picks.

Plus that we want to have "best-approximate" result in case the ideal is impossible.

Knapsack problems are classified as NP, and getting an exact or best-possible is in general - either hard or very time-taking. After spending some time on the google, I have not found any ready-to-use algorithms that would solve money problem with exact-N-picks, and probably that class of problem is simply known under some other name, which I cannot recall now. I suggest you very much to search, or ask a question on how to classify such problem. If someone more fluent in algorithmic nomenclature answers, you might even find instantly a working solution.

Other things to consider: how serious is your "best result" need, and, really, how much close does it need to be? How much keys there will be with respect to the number of strings? How much will the word count of the strings vary? Any extra conditions on that may help in dropping the knapsack and using some naiive methods that will happen to be safe with those conditions.

For example, if the number of remaining (NKey-NSstrings) is low, just fire a complete exponential search that will check all possibilities and you will surely get the best result.

Elsewise, if you do not need a very best result and also (NKeys-NStrings) is high and also the word count is relatively evenly-shaped, then you probably could just do a simple greedy assignement and the several items that were wrongly assigned would make the average only a little off (several items divided by the high NKeys-NStrings = low fraction of the average).

In other cases, or if you really need the best match, you probably will need to get into "dynamic programming" or "integer linear programming" that can generate approximate solutions for similar problems.

If I have any thoughts on that, I'll add them and leave a comment, but actually I doubt. Out of my memory, I've written everything, and I could give you more pointers more only if I'd actually stick my nose to the algo-books again, which I sadly have to little time for that now:) Drop me a note if you find by chance the correct classification of the problem!

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad you have some solution:)

I've played a bit with your nevest code, let's have:

```
array1 =  [320, 321, 322, 323, 324]
array2 = ["a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a", "b"]

irb(main):071:0> pp hash_from_arrays(array1, array2)
{320=>"a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a",
 321=>"a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a",
 322=>"a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a",
 323=>"a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a",
 324=>"a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a"}
```

1) Is it OK that the "B" was not used at all?
2) array2 has 17 words, divided by 5 keys in array1 = avg 3.4 words per key. The result has avg 16 words per key, this is faar from 3.4. Obviously, if "b" was used a few times, the avg would be closer to 3.4.

Or maybe again I did not understand what distribution/average you have in your mind?

Comment: thanks for looking into this. 1) No, B should be definitely used, I guess this means that my solution is not really solving it completely (or at all for that matter) 2) In this case I would hope B to show up once in the last key-value pair (it is closest that we can get to even distribution without breaking the integrity of strings, which is important).. If you have any suggestions on how to fix this, that would be great!

Comment: I thought that B should appear and that's why I posted that example. I don't try to troll/irritate you, but how is it that you say that in this case the "B" should appear once, only in the last pair? That would give an average of (16*4+1)/5=13.0 > 3.4. Lets say sixteen 'a's is "A" and that single 'b' is B. For distribution 2*A+3*B you get avg word cound of 7, a two times closer to 3.4 than that, and for 1*A+4*B you get 4.0, which is the the closest possible to 3.4. Please clarify: is it 1*A+4*B the best? Or did I completely misunderstood and 16*A+1*B is the best (as you now said)? If so-why?

Comment: oh my, very sorry for confusion. You are right. I actually realized I am asking the question in reverse. Seems that I actually need the arrays to be distributed in reverse (array1 to array2). I will update the question now.